# Can't download files with PowerShell IE COM Object [with login]

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, com, webrequest

I have a script using PowerShells IE COM Object to login to a site and navigate to a page with PDFs (that I wish to download). I am using IE COM object to do all the navigation, and Invoke-WebRequest for the actual download. Issue is when the PDF files download they are size 2kb and can't be opened. I have a strong feeling this is a session issue and IE must be forgetting that I am logged in somehow. Any way to make IE remember I am logged in when so that I can download the files successfully?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

```
    $ie = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application
    $ie.visible = $true

    # Navigate to home page
    $ie.navigate($URL)
    while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -Seconds 3}

    $Username = $ie.Document.getElementsByName("userName")
    $Username.item(0).value = "username"

    $Password = $ie.Document.getElementsByName("password")
    $Password.item(0).value = "pass"

    $AcceptTerms = $ie.Document.getElementById("useAddtnlField")
    $AcceptTerms.checked = $true

    $Btn = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("span") | ? {$_.title -match 'Login'}
    $Btn.click()
    while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -Seconds 2}

    # ---- logged in ----


     # -- Opens link in new window (due to JS) --
$ie.Navigate("https://chaseloanmanager.chase.com/Chaselock/ViewOnlineGuide.aspx")
                    while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -Seconds 2}
```

After that last navigate, I lose the $ie object and can no longer do anything with it. If I create a new `$ie2` object, and continue the script using `$ie2`, the files are unable to be opened when finished. I was also unsuccessful getting access to the window using `Shell.Application` and `Windows()` method as to try and reference the original `$ie` window. Anyways, I think I need to complete the script using the original `$ie` object so that I am recognized as logged in throughout the process and can have a valid download at the end. Hopefully that makes sense and can help someone help me. Thanks

Comment: Please provide a sample of what you're doing in the PowerShell script, so we can better understand how you're calling the download process explicitly.  :-)

Comment: Just added some more info to the OP, thanks ;)